# Applescript - Check Chrome for Window IDs

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

I am trying to have Applescript ask Google Chrome for all of the window IDs. Then if a certain window Id is not present, to do something.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish (arrows indicate the area that needs assistance):

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    -->get window ids of all windows 
    -->if window id 47 is not present then
       do something
    end if 
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "exists":

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    if window id 47 exists then
        display dialog "is present"
    else
        display dialog "is not present"
    end if
end tell
```